# Differential archive of a large array series

Tags: c#, python, c++, arrays, unit-testing

I'm building a unit test framework for a specific program that operates on a large set of  2-dimensional arrays. These arrays contain floating-point numbers and are 500x700 in size. Each unit test inputs a few arrays and checks the unit output with other data. Each test should be run on a long sequence of inputs (about 2000 unique data sets). All the input data can't be generated on the fly, because it takes way too long (over 10 minutes). So, I need to store all the input data somewhere. But storing all of it uncompressed would take about 100 GB of storage or more because of the number of modules. Regular compression methods cut this number in half, which is still too much, considering this amount could potentially grow 10 times in the future.

Now, each dataset in a sequence doesn't differ much from the previous one, so some kind of differential archive would be a great way of solving the problem. The data would be written to the database once and then each test will read it's portion many times, so reading operations should be quick.
The question is: is there some kind of database that supports this type of storage out of the box? Currently, I'm using Pytables/HDF5, but I wasn't able to find anything for this particular need except implementing it myself. I'm looking for literally any differential encoding/archiving software that would support my data and would not be too hard to use from a program written in C++, C# or Python.

Comment: What a brain dump without a single LOC ...

Comment: The numbers aren't well identified. AFAIKS, the simple `array` is 500x700. A `sequence` contains 2000 `array`s. That's 2,800,000,000 (float) or 5,600,000,000 (double). I have 101.913.144.000 on my slightly outdated notebook HD. Or buy some external HD with several TBs for less than what one hour of coding costs... Where is the problem?